# Partition a list into TradingChartformat

Tags: list-manipulation, finance

I want to make a stock chart by using `TradingChart` with my own data. But, the imported data is in the format
`price={{MM/DD/YYYY1,open1, high1, low1, close1}, {MM/DD/YYYY2,open2, high2, low2, close2}, {MM/DD/YYYY3,open3, high3, low3, close3}...}`
I want to partition my list into the TradingChart format as
`price={date1,{open1,high1,low1,close1,volume1}},…}`
But I have no idea how to partition with different size like the format. Could you please help me? Another question is in this case, can I use
`DatePattern[{"Month", "Day", "Year"}, "/"]`
in order to not change all my date, which is in `MM/DD/YYYY`. My understanding is if I use `DatePattern[{"Month", "Day", "Year"}, "/"]`, I don't have to change the date from `MM/DD/YYYY` to `{y,m,d}`, is it correct? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `Composition[Through, {First, Rest}] /@ price`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways. Here is just one.

```
Transpose[{DateList[{#, {"Month", "Day", "Year"}}] & /@ 
   price[[All, 1]], {##, 0} & @@@ price[[All, 2 ;;]]}]
```

Example:

```
price = {{"10/10/2015", Sequence @@ RandomReal[{90, 100}, 4]}, 
  {"10/11/2015", Sequence @@ RandomReal[{90, 100}, 4]}, 
  {"10/12/2015", Sequence @@ RandomReal[{90, 100}, 4]}}
```

> ```
> {{"10/10/2015", 99.4675, 91.3724, 99.8884, 94.7369}, 
>  {"10/11/2015", 94.7509, 91.7196, 91.8822, 91.2132}, 
>  {"10/12/2015", 99.3705, 97.0185, 96.3484, 92.8318}}
> ```

```
TradingChart[
 Transpose[{DateList[{#, {"Month", "Day", "Year"}}] & /@ 
    price[[All, 1]], {##, 0} & @@@ price[[All, 2 ;;]]}]]
```

> [image: TC]

---

A possible [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html) (extended version of the [comment by J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101624/partition-a-list-into-tradingchartformat/101628#comment275652_101624)) is

```
Composition[Through, {DateList[{First@#, {"Month", "Day", "Year"}}] &, Append[0]@*Rest}] /@ 
 price
```